# How to use the JavaScript "debugger;" keyword in Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I am attempting to use an existing Appcelerator app.

The code is full of the "debugger;" keyword and the app will not build.

Appcelerator is reporting an error for every instance of:

```
debugger;
```

**Error**: *Syntax Error: unexpected token "debugger" - JavaScript Syntax Problem*

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

I am sure the code builds / compiles as-is for the original developer (who I am unable to contact).

Comment: OK. wait ill search again @Nwqport99

Answer (score 1):

In Appcelerator Studio `debugger;` works as a breakpoint. You can simply remove it.

Comment: When the `debugger;` keyword is used in my code I receive an error building the app and cannot run/debug at all.

Comment: Make sure you only have these lines in your app when you [run the app in debug-mode from Studio](http://skypanther.com/2013/02/breakpoint-debugging-an-alloy-app/).